# php/mysql maximum connections reached

Tags: mysql, webhooks

I have an application that connects to a 3rd party. They fire web-hooks simultaneously at a time. Sometimes the hooks are about 1000 and over. The problem is that, my script connects to a database and save the hooks. These 1000 queries fired simultaneously on my system makes the system goes off. How effectively can i handle the web hooks?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is, after every query, is close the connection. This will ensure that no connection stays open or is stacked on top of each other.

You will have to re-initiate the connection before launching a new query of course.

You could also increase the number of connection allowed to your MySQL database. This should be changed in your MySQL configuration (usually at /etc/mysql/my.conf ( http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql_intro.html )) by changing the "max_connections" variable/configuration value. ( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_connections )

Good luck and if you have any questions don't hesitate to ask.

Best regards,